# google-spreadsheet скопировать одну колонку в другую node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-spreadsheet

У меня есть колонка BM и колонка BN. Мне нужно скопировать значения колонки BM с клеток 4 по 29 в колонку BN. Использовал методы sheet.copyPaste() и sheet.getCellsInRange(), но ничего не привело к результатам.

использую - https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet

Comment: Покажите код, которым вы пытаетесь это сделать

Comment: async execute(client) {
        await doc.loadInfo();
        await doc.loadCells();
        const sheet = doc.sheetsById[1162940648];

        sheet.copyPaste('BM4:BM28', 'BN4:BN28')
    },
};

Comment: А че за node.js? В гугле есть встроенный редактор вроде

Comment: Кстати, default пишется через a, если не знали))